# DOMException: The source image could not be decoded

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, web-worker

What could be the reason that the method below throws `DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.`?

```
async function drawImage(blob) {
    console.log('Start draw image.')
    console.log(blob);
    if(context === undefined) {
        console.log('Context is not defined.');
    } else if(blob.type === 'image/jpeg') {
        console.log('Drawing image');
        // Error: DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.
        const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
        context.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        bmp.close();
    }
}
```

The code above runs inside a web worker, specifically after a decode process:

```
onmessage = async function (e) {
    let jpegBlob = decodeBinary(e.data);
    drawImage(jpegBlob);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a broken image would cause this.

```js
// The same would happen in a Worker thread,
// it's just easier for StackSnippet to log from main thread
const context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

function decodeBinary() {
  return new Blob(["not an image"], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
async function drawImage(blob) {
  console.log('Start draw image.')
  console.log(blob);
  if (context === undefined) { // beware, unsupported call to getContext returns `null`, not `undefined`
    console.log('Context is not defined.');
  } else if (blob.type === 'image/jpeg') {
    console.log('Drawing image');
    // Error: DOMException: The source image could not be decoded.
    const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
    context.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    bmp.close();
  }
}

onmessage = async function(e) {
  let jpegBlob = decodeBinary(e.data);
  drawImage(jpegBlob).catch(console.error);
}

self.postMessage('', '*');
```

So you will want to check the content of your Blob, and to debug your `decodeBinary` function.

As a first step, you can check if the file signature matches one of the JPEG image:
    `new Uint8Array( (await blob.slice(0,3).arrayBuffer()) ).join("") === "255216255";`

You can also try to pass that Blob to your main thread, create a `blob:` URL from it, and try to load it in an `<img>` tag, your browser may be more explicit about what the issue is.

Comment: Apparently there was a missing byte in the video decoder, the  main UI `createImageBitmap` is much for forgiving than the web worker implementation maybe that's why it renders in the browser but fails in the web worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, where i tried to load a image url from an api.

I added `http://` at the beginning of url and my issue is solved.